# generate thumbnail from the middle of every scenes changes in a video using ffmpeg or other software

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, thumbnails, scene

Is there a way to generate thumbnails from scene changes using ffmpeg?  Instead of picking the I-Frames but the middle of two I-Frames?  This is assuming the middle of two major changes is usually the best time to take thumbnail shot from.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way!

Execute this command:

> ffmpeg -i **yourvideo.mp4** -vf
>   select="eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync 0 -an
>   **thumb%03d.png**

It is really simple. ffmpeg algorithms will do all the work and generate thumbnails from the middle of every scene change.

The items on bold:

yourvideo.mp4 (you need to change this to your video input)

thumb%03d.png (This is your output)